# Existing Neo4j 2.1.7 DB won't start with 2.2

Tags: neo4j

In the past - I've switched from 2.1.5 to 2.1.7 (and other versions previously) in this way:

1. Unzip files to a 'neo4j-community-{version}' folder
2. Edit 'logging.properties', 'neo4j-server.properties', 'windows-wrapper-logging.properties' files and change locations with a value of `data/{something}` to be `../data/{something}` *(where {something} is rrd,db etc)*
3. Start the server by `bin/neo4j.bat` to test it's working, Java window pops up and the browser is contactable - before installing it.

So far, no problems.

**But** this process doesn't seem to be working for the 2.2 release. I follow the same procedure against a 2.1.7 DB that I *know* is fine. When I perform step 3 above, the Java window pops up and then pretty much instantly closes itself, and I get the following text in the console:

```
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: Params
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties="conf/neo4j-server.properties"
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: -Djava.util.logging.config.file="conf/logging.properties"
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: -Dlog4j.configuration="file:conf/log4j.properties"
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: "-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow"
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: "-XX:hashCode=5"
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source="zip"
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: Classpath: "-classpath" "k:\Neo4J\neo4j-community-2.2.0\bin\..\lib\concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar;k:\Neo4J\neo4j-community-2.2.0\bin\..\lib\lucene-core-3.6.2.jar;k:\Neo4J\neo4j-community-2.2.0\bin\..\lib\neo4j-consistenc... --- MORE ---
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: Main class: org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper
    Mar 26, 2015 1:58:56 PM org.neo4j.wrapper.NeoServiceWrapper launchAsConsoleApp
    INFO: Args:
```

Now, I've changed the `.properties` files to point to `../data-new/{something}` and when I run the `bin\neo4j.bat` file it creates the `data-new` folder as expected, so I know the format is correct. It just won't open the existing databases.

Is there anything I can look at to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable the store upgrade?

try to remove the # in neo4j.properties:
`allow_store_upgrade=true`

Comment: I have indeed tried this, but to no avail - my understanding from http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0/deployment-upgrading.html is that from a 2.1.x database instance, the upgrade is automatic, not requiring the `allow_store_upgrade=true` toggle.

Comment: Can you share your messages.log?

Comment: Ahh ha! Turns out the DB wasn't shutting down correctly - perhaps as a result of running it as a service - messages.log showed that - and then once it was shut down properly, it *did* require the `allow_store_upgrade` toggle - so the correct answer - thank you @Ron